# Empty SQL query/Value in Gridview Error

Tags: c#, asp.net, t-sql, gridview, postback

I am building a reservation app and I am trying to fix a bug - I reserved every workstation for x amount of days so 0 workstations should show in my GridView - However when I click that day in my Calendar the program crashes and gives me this error

```
  Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
```

Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

```
    Source Error: 


  Line 246:            gvAvailable.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
  Line 247:            gvAvailable.DataBind();
  Line 248:            gvAvailable.HeaderRow.Cells[0].Text = "Workstation";
  Line 249:            gvAvailable.HeaderRow.Cells[1].Text = "Location";
  Line 250:        }
```

I tested the query it's executing when that date is selected and it's an empty query which is correct since all stations are booked however the program crashes. Any help guys?

Comment: check if table is NOTHING/NULL first before setting datasource

Comment: How are you filling your dataset?  Seems to me that `ds.Tables` is probably empty so `ds.Tables[0]` results in a null reference.

Comment: if (ds.Tables != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    gvAvailable.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
                    gvAvailable.DataBind();
                    gvAvailable.HeaderRow.Cells[0].Text = "Workstation";
                    gvAvailable.HeaderRow.Cells[1].Text = "Location";
                }
                catch (ArgumentNullException)
                {

                }
            }

Answer (score 0):

Realized the correct syntax to check if the dataset is empty or not

```
 ds != null && ds.Tables.Count > 0 && ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0
```